# Florida room enclosed

Tags: deck, florida

My Florida room is at the back of house, which slopes down a hill. While the house itself is block construction, the Florida room addition has been built on a deck-like foundation and also had a deck added around it. We are concerned that this area of the house might slope away from the house with time (due to it being on sand and on a hill) and are wondering who we might be able to hire to come look at it, as it’s not a “deck” in the traditional sense. Our home inspector said nothing in regards to this area (~1 year ago), my husband is just concerned and wants to know how up to code it is. Thanks

Comment: Without pics and a detailed description there is no way we can tell if it is "to code".  However a general contractor should be able to tell you if there is a reason for concern.  Get a few opinions if you can.